# Access a service exposed by AWS ELB from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I have a AWS Lambda function written in Java which is trying to access a SOAP API service exposed by an ELB.
Both lambda function and the ELB are in default VPC. I have ensured that the Lambda is attached to all the subnets within the default VPC. The lambda function has the AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole  access. I have added SG of Lambda to the inbound rules of the ELB SG.

But when I run the lambda, I get the following -
Caused by: org.apache.commons.httpclient.ConnectTimeoutException: The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 30000 ms
.
.
.
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Comment: Even with your changes it sounds like there is something blocking communication from Lambda to ELB.

Answer (score 3):

If the Elastic Load Balancer is publicly accessible, then it is only reachable via a Public IP address.

When an AWS Lambda function is attached to a VPC, it only has a private IP address. To access the Internet, it would need a NAT Gateway or NAT Instance in the public subnet to send traffic to the Internet, and then back into the load balancer. If this is your current configuration, then please note that the Security Group on the Load Balancer possibly isn't recognizing the public IP address of the Lambda function (that is assigned by the NAT), so the inbounds security group on the Load Balancer isn't allowing the traffic. You can test if this is the situation by temporarily allowing ALL traffic into the Load Balancer.

Better options:

**Option 1: Do not attach the Lambda function to the VPC**

When *not* connected to a VPC, the Lambda function will be connected to the Internet. It will then be able to access the Load Balancer via a public IP address.

**Option 2: Use an Internal Load Balancer**

If the Load Balancer does not need to be accessed from the Internet, change it to an Internal Load Balancer. The Lambda function will then be able to communicate with it via its private IP address.